# PHP Interface not enforcing function list

Tags: php, oop

In the following code segment I have a class that implements an interface. However, I have a function in the class that is not present in the interface, and when executed no error is generated.

It is my understanding that an error will be generated. What am I missing?

```
<?php

/* Connection parameters for application database. */
defined('DB_SERVER') ? NULL : define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
defined('DB_USER') ? NULL : define('DB_USER', 'someUser');
defined('DB_PWD') ? NULL : define('DB_PWD', 'somePassword');
defined('DB_NAME') ? NULL : define('DB_NAME', 'sandbox');

interface dbAPI {
    public function __construct();
    public function __destruct();
    public function main();
}

class dbMysqli implements dbAPI {
    protected $conn = null;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->conn = $this->dbConnect();
        if(!$this->conn) exit("ERROR: Could not connect to database.");
    }

    public function __destruct() {

    }

    public function dbConnect() {
        return mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PWD, DB_NAME);
    }

    public function main() {
        echo "\n\nMAIN\n\n";
    }
}
$dbObj = new dbMysqli();
$dbObj->main();
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An interface specifies which methods are required by the implementing class. Not vice-versa.

In you example `dbAPI` specified that methods `__construct`, `__destruct` and `main` must be specified by `dbMysqli` as it implements that interface.

`dbMysqli` can implement as many other methods as wanted, even when they're not required by the interface. You can even implement multiple interfaces in the same class:

```
interface A {
    public function go();
}
interface B {
    public function stop();
}
class Car implements A, B {
    public function go() {
        // Do something
    }
    public function stop() {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ronni. The misunderstanding on my part was I didn't think the class could have functions in addition to those specified in the interface. I'm novice at OOP, so I can now see the logic of allowing the class the flexibility of adding more functions.

Answer (score 2):

When using interfaces, classes must implement all methods but you can also implement additional methods if needed.

In your case, dbConnect is missing from the interface but your class implemented it.